# Is it possible to retrieve documents along with their mappings to avoid race condition?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

In Elasticsearch, when you are querying documents and also interested in having their type mappings there is a possibility of race condition, when mappings are changed after you queried documents.

Is it possible to avoid it somehow? For example by querying documents and type mappings in one request?

Comment: If you need to prevent mappings from being changed dynamically, you can do it by setting [`"dynamic": false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html). Doing that you can be sure that there is no race condition and mappings can only change when you decide to do it explicitly.